# Whis my planetary volume formula wrong? (volume = mass/density)

Tags: earth, mathematics

I'm having trouble with this and am unsure what I'm doing wrong. Let's use Earth as an example.

Earth has a mass of [5,972,168,000,000,000,000,000,000 (5.97E+27) kg](https://www.google.com/search?q=earth%27s%20mass) and a density of [5513.4 kg/m3 or 5.5134 g/cm3](https://www.google.com/search?q=earth%27s%20density).

Volume = mass / density.

The calculation gives me a result of 1,086,109,090,909,090,000,000,000.00 (1.09E+24) m3. However, the Earth's volume is
[1,083,210,000,000,000.00 m3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth). That's a 1 billion times difference.

Is there a discreprancy with the units [this question advised to always use kg and m2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125543/given-the-mass-and-composition-of-a-planet-can-one-determine-what-the-radius-sh)?

Comment: Earth's volume from wikipedia is $1.0832 \times10^{12} $ km, not $1.0832 \times10^{12} $  m. Correct this error and you'll see you calculated approximately the right answer the first time.

Comment: I cannot correct the volume as this is the value I'm trying to calculate from the forumla. I can only change the mass or density. I can however fix my reference to know what the value should be, so thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Your Earth mass is off by a factor 1000, that's jupiter mass. The mass of earth is is $6\cdot 10^{24}$kg.

Answer (score 2):

## Your Earth mass is off by a factor of 1000

As @planetmaker has pointed out, the mass of the earth is $6$$⋅$$10^{24}$ kg, instead of $6$$⋅$$10^{27}$.

Second, $km^{3}$ and $m^{3}$ are different things. $km^{3}$ is off $m^{3}$ by a factor of 1 billion ($1km^{3}$=$10^9m^{3}$).

Correct your calculations using these factors. If calculations are correct, you should obtain $1.08321 × 10^{21}$$m^3$ as your correct answer.